# Conformal map from $\mathbb{D}$ to right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

The question is to find a conformal map from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Rez>0\}$ such that $z=1$ goes to $z=0$.

My thoughts:

We know that map $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to the right half plane.  However, $f(1)=\infty\neq1=f(0)$.  So is there a way that an algebraic way for me to manipulate this map so that $f(1)=f(0)$ while still preserving that it is conformal?

Comment: Note that $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ preserves positivity on the real part, so just flip your function - note that you need $f(1)=0$ not $f(1)=f(0)$ since that cannot happen for a conformal map

Comment: @Conrad but doesn't $z\mapsto\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ take RHP to $\mathbb{D}$?  So would a conformal map relating the two of them not matter which direction you go in?    Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what is your question - the map above takes the unit disc to the right hand plane, sending $1$ to $0$ which is what you asked - obviously it is defined on the right hand plane too but that is a different issue